# Fix sum of weights in a Keras/TensorFlow convolution filter

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a 2D convolution filter layer (call it 7x7) in the neural network. I want to constrain the filter to have its weights add up to 0. (This is a common requirement for convolution filters in image processing - the idea is that the filter is sensitive to the local variations in brightness, but not to the absolute level of brightness.) This is more or less equivalent to having a 48-weight layer whose inputs are x[-3,-3]-x[0,0], x[-3,-2]-x[0,0], ... x[3,3]-x[0,0].

For some reason, I don't see any native functionality to impose this constraint.

Things I tried so far:

- Don't impose the constraint. Very bad for convergence (varying overall levels of brightness act as a massive source of noise that prevents the network from converging.)
- Code a custom regularizer for the layer:

e.g.

```
class FixSum(Regularizer):      
def call(self, x):
    reg=0.01*math_ops.reduce_sum(math_ops.abs(math_ops.reduce_sum(x,axis=(0,1))))
    return reg
```

Bad for convergence, especially at the regularizer strength where it is actually effective at driving the sum of weights to the vicinity of zero.

- Code a custom constraint for the layer:

e.g.

```
class TestConstraint(Constraint):
      def __init__(self, N, target_sum):
        self.target_sum = tf.keras.backend.variable(target_sum,dtype="float32")
        self.N = N
      def __call__(self, w):
        t = math_ops.reduce_sum(x,axis=(0,1),keepdims=True) - self.target_sum
        t /= self.N
        return w - tf.keras.backend.repeat_elements(tf.keras.backend.repeat_elements(t, w.shape[0], 0), w.shape[1], 1)
```

Sort of works, but the convergence rate leaves something to be desired

- Manually construct all the differences. Instead of a simple

  Conv2D(n, (7,7),...)

I'd do

```
Conv2D(48, (7,7), trainable=False, ...)
Conv2D(n, (1,1), ...)
```

where the first Conv2D has its weights set at the outset to produce x[-3,-3]-x[0,0], etc.

Convergence rate is good, but performance is not so good. And it does not scale too well (if I increase the kernel from 7x7 to 15x15, that would increase the computational complexity of this "fake layer" by a factor of ~20.)

Is there anything else I should try?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `abs` with `square` in the regularizer? Also, you don't need 48 maps in the non-trainable layer if all that you want is just to subtract local average from your input.

Comment: ...actually, I would just start with subtracting the local average to test your assumption that it's the absolute brightness that prevents your network from converging. It may as well be not the case.